# RouteBuilder vs EndpointRoutBuilder in .Net

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, endpoint

I am trying to learn behind the scene of Routing and I find out that `WebApplication` implements `IEndpointRouteBuilder` which allows it to define routes for example using `MapGet` or even the `UseEndpoint` middleware itself use it behind the scene. I also see another type and interface which was very similar to that but not related in any way to it: `RouteBuilder`. It also has methods starting with Map and seems that have same usage with `IEndpointRouteBuilder`. Where is used `RouteBuilder` in the routing in .Net 6 and does it is obsolete or it is used yet? What is the usage then which can not implemented by `IEndpointRouteBuilder`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that before current approach of UseRouting() and UseEndpoints() the approach is to use UseRouter(IRouter router) middleware which get an IRouter argument which get from RouterBuilder. More information in following link:
[Routing in Asp.Net 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)